# Storing an array online for access in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, web

I have an array of integers that I'm using in an iOS app which is liable to change. Instead of updating the app each time the integers change, is there a way I can store the array online and access it within the app?
Where would I be able to store the information and what is the mechanism used to retrieve it in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

CloudKit will probably work, but it seems like overkill, especially if the dataset isn't per-user. If don't mind paying for the backend, Amazon AWS can provide a place to host the dataset for use in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Parse heres a tutorial on how to set it up, https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the data served by any web server in the world. Then you can query it, either using the standard `NSURL*` family (and then parsing the contents, depending on the chosen format), or using libraries such as [RestKit](http://restkit.org) that will do both at once.